# How to Schedule Python Code To Run Daily Using Apschedulers?

Tags: python, cron, scheduler, apscheduler

I am trying to use Apschedulers to Run a code Daily  But i am facing some issue
Here is Code :

```
async def job():
      print("Boss Wake Up")


scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(job, "cron", day_of_week="mon-sun", hour=21, minute=10)
scheduler.start()
```

But its not working starting from today. why? i wanna make it start from day one and run daily. Can anyone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: `mon-sun` covers every day of the week so it is redundant (just like how you don't have to specify that it should run every year or month either).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job(IntervalTrigger(seconds=10))  #set the interval you need
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every 10 seconds.')

sched.start()
```

You can use BackgroundScheduler() if you want to run this in background

Answer (score 0):

You still need to run the asyncio event loop. Add the following block:

```
try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```